# ISP error: 'DDRD' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, terminal, arduino, compiler-warnings

I have a problem for my Arduino as ISP: I have followed the tuto of Michael Holachek with this video http://michael.holachek.com/2012/09/avr-programming/  and when I write in the Terminal :
"`make flash`" it said a lot of error:

```
avr-gcc -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=8000000 -mmcu=attiny84 -c main.c -o main.o

main.c:1:1: warning: "F_CPU" redefined

<command line="">:1:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition

main.c: In function 'main':

main.c:8: error: 'DDRD' undeclared (first use in this function)

main.c:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

main.c:8: error: for each function it appears in.)

main.c:12: error: 'PORTD' undeclared (first use in this function)

main.c:17:2: warning: no newline at end of file

make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

yet I have include avr/io, can somebody help me ?